# How to add IP sniffing filter in Scapy (Python)

Tags: python, scapy, packet

I'm trying to write a code in Python using Scapy, which will do **the following**:

Given ***ip1***, ***ip2*** - 2 IPv4 addresses, sniff all of the packets which their source IP is ***ip1*** and their destination IP is ***ip2***, using `Scapy.sniff()`.

Even though I've tried to google it a lot, I didn't find any way to do this. I'll be glad to have some help in writing it. Thanks!

Comment: https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#sniffing

Comment: I’ve looked at this documentation and unfortunately couldn’t find a solution over there. Could you please help me with that?

Comment: Try passing `filter="(ip.src == <ip1>) and (ip.dst == <ip2>)"` to `sniff`. Replace `<ip1>` and `<ip2>` with the actual IP addresses (e.g. 1.2.3.4).